# TFS workspace naming guidance, where?

Tags: tfs, workspace

Is there any guidance about workspace naming and workspace mapping in TFS (2010) ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any specific guidance on this, but after a couple years, we've primarily settled on a single workspace mapped to root `$/`.  We've been operating like this for probably a year with 80+ developers, and haven't seen much of an issue.

In my opinion, this is valid, as is the idea of one workspace per Team Project, as long as you don't have a whole lot of Team Projects to deal with.

Comment: We've been doing the same thing here and it's been working well since 2005.

Comment: I found a some slides from Marcel de Vries (InfoSupport & MVP). He also recommends one single root mapping, this makes searching easier. What I couldn't find is a workspace naming convention...

Comment: I don't know if there needs to be one, except for-- make it easy to differentiate.  I currently have WorkLocal, MergeSpace, and ComponentUpgrade.  My main space is WorkLocal, with the other two being used for a couple of special efforts that are going on.

Answer (score 1):

For the Mapping aspect there is nothing to add to the first answer as- "Map to root $/" approach seems to be the most used.
However, the MSDN [Basic Guidelines for Creating a Workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138514.aspx) seem to suggest a different approach:

> If you want to work with files from a single folder, map to one that is as close to the level of the team project collection as you can but no closer than you must. That way, you will get all the files that you need without getting many that you do not need.

I would tend to say that workspace naming conventions are only helpful if you need to create multiple workspaces on the same workstation. That would be the case if you need to work on different codebases hosted in different team collections or on different branches of the same codebase.

Like mentioned in previous feedback, I did not find a reference specifically addressing the topic, but the "[Naming your TFS workspace](http://help.teamprise.com/3.2/index.jsp?topic=/com.teamprise.explorer.help/explorerdoc/gs_workspace_name.html)" article from the old TeamPrise Explorer documentation has some good suggestions:

> (...) give workspaces a name that includes your machine name, your deliverable, and branch if applicable.

"Deliverable" is organization specific, but can likely be related to a single team project so that the name of the project could be used to correlate the workspace to it (rather than using a different name for essentially the same thing).